# Efficient SQL to merge results or leave to client browser javascript?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, pivot

I was wondering, what is the most efficient way of combining results into a single result.

I want to turn

```
Num  Ani   Country
---- ----- -------
22   cows  Canada
20   pigs  Canada
40   cows  USA
34   pigs  USA
```

into:

```
cows  pigs  Country
----- ----- -------
22    20    Canada
40    34    USA
```

I want to know if it would be better to use SQL only or if I should feed the whole query result set to the user. Once given to the user, I could use JavaScript to parse it into the desired format.

Also, I do not know exactly how I would change this into the right format for a SQL query. The only way I can think of approaching this SQL statement is very roundabout with dynamically creating a temporary table.

Comment: Assuming your results are really that small, this kind of optimization is totally pointless and a waste of your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you're after is called "pivoting" - the [PIVOT info page has a little more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/info):

```
  SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t.ani = 'cows' THEN t.num ELSE NULL END) AS cows,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.ani = 'pigs' THEN t.num ELSE NULL END) AS pigs,
         t.country
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.country
ORDER BY t.country
```

Comment: ...and yes, pivoting on the server is more efficient, you don't have to push all of those bytes down the wire, just the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an efficient way using a 2-D array on the client-side (php) to achieve the pivoting. To address Ken Downs' concerns about byte pushing, a ragged raw pivot data consumes less bytes than a fully materialized 2-D pivot table, the simple case is

```
cows | pigs | sheep | goats | country
1      null   null    null    Canada
null   2      null    null    USA
null   null   3       null    Egypt
null   null   null    4       England
```

which is only 4 rows of raw data (each being 3 columns).

Doing it in the front end also solves the issue of dynamic-pivoting.  If your number of pivot columns is unknown, then you would require a MySQL procedure to build up a dynamic sql statement of the pattern "MAX(CASE....)" for each column.

There are advantages to doing this on the client side

1. can be done (at least considered as an alternative)
2. can be rendered earlier, if the savings in network traffic is significant despite requiring either (1) php pivottable construction or (2) client side javascript
3. does not require a MySQL procedure for dynamic pivoting